# Python how to use Tkinter GUI without interfering the main code loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I would like to implement a very simple GUI for my project. I was previously using just Print statements to output some text and data. However, that is not very conveneint and since a person will need to operate a device that I am coding, he needs to be clearly see the instructions that I am going to display on GUI.

my code:

```
main()
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect( host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database )
counter = 0

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("GUI")
window.geometry("400x200")

while(1):

    # OPERACIJOS KODAI:
    # 0 - PILDYMAS
    # 1 - KOMPLEKTAVIMAS
    # 2 - NETINKAMAS KODAS
    tk.Label(window,text = "Scan barcode here:").pack()
    entry = tk.Entry(window)
    entry.pack()
    var = tk.IntVar()
    button = tk.Button(window,text="Continue",command = lambda: var.set(1))
    button.pack()
    print("waiting...")
    button.wait_variable(var)
    result = entry.get()
    print("Entry string=",result)
    var.set(0)

    
    operacijos_kodas=Scanning_operation(myConnection,result)
    print("operacijos kodas=",operacijos_kodas)
    if(operacijos_kodas == 0):
        tk.label(window,text = "PILDYMO OPERACIJA:").pack()

        pildymo_operacija(myConnection)
   
        
    elif(operacijos_kodas == 1):
        tk.Label(window,text = "PAKAVIMO OPERACIJA:").pack()

        insertData_komplektacija(myConnection,"fmb110bbv801.csv");
        update_current_operation(myConnection);
        picking_operation();
        
    elif(operacijos_kodas == 2):
        print("Skenuokite dar karta")
        #break
   window.mainloop();
```

Nothing is being displayed. It just opens up an empty GUI window.

First of all, I am unsure where should I call function `window.mainloop()`.

Secondly, since my system runs in an infinite while loop ( the operation starts when a user scans a bar-code, then he completes an operation and the while loop starts over again (waiting for user to scan a bar-code). So I just simply have to display some text and allow user to input data in the text box.

Could someone suggest me whether this GUI is suitable for my needs or I should look for an alternatives?

UPDATE*********************

I have tried to use mainloop:

```
print ("Using mysql.connector…")
main()
GPIO_SETUP() 
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect( host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database )
counter = 0
window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(False,False)
window_height = 1000
window_width = 1200
#window.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
#window.config(height=500,width=500)
#can = Canvas(window,bg='red',height=100,width=100)
#can.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor='center')
window.title("GUI")
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height= window.winfo_screenheight()
x = int((screen_width/ 2) - (window_width / 2))
y = int((screen_height/ 2) - (window_height / 2))   
window.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width,window_height,x,y))
label1=Label(window,text = "SKENUOKITE BARKODA(GUID) ARBA DAIKTO RIVILINI KODA:")
label1.pack()
entry = Entry(window)
entry.pack()
var = tk.IntVar()
button = Button(window,text="Testi operacija",width = 30,command = lambda: var.set(1))
button.pack()
#button2 = Button(window,text="RESTARTUOTI SISTEMA",width = 30,command = restart_devices())
#button2.pack()
print("waiting...")    
button.wait_variable(var)
Scanned_serial = entry.get()
print("Entry string=",Scanned_serial) 
var.set(0)
label2=Label(window,text = "Vykdoma operacija:")
label2.pack()
window.update()
window.after(1000,Full_operation(Scanned_serial,label2,window))
window.mainloop()
```

This is my code. As you can see. i call Full_operation function and then window.mainloop()

my Full_operation:

```
def Full_operation(Scanned_serial,label2,window):
    operacijos_kodas=Scanning_operation(myConnection,Scanned_serial)
    print("operacijos kodas=",operacijos_kodas)
    if(operacijos_kodas == 0):

        label2.config(text = "SPAUSKITE MYGTUKA ANT DEZES KURIA NORITE PILDYTI:")#update the label2
        window.update()#call update to update the label
        pildymo_operacija(myConnection,Scanned_serial,label2,window)
        
    elif(operacijos_kodas == 1):
        insertData_komplektacija(myConnection,"fmb110bbv801.csv");
        update_current_operation(myConnection);
        #label2.config(text = "IMKITE DAIKTUS IS ZALIOS DEZUTES:")#update the label2
        picking_operation(myConnection,label2);
        
    elif(operacijos_kodas == 2):
        print("Skenuokite dar karta")
        label2.config(text = "NUSKENUOTAS NEGALIMAS KODAS:")#update the label2
        window.update()#call update to update the label
```

How can I ensure that everytime I enter FUll_operation function I start from clean GUI again and start another operation.

Now I am able to complete operation once. After that, the GUI is not responsive.
I have added a print statement at the beggining of my full_operation and it does not execute after I complete it once so my mainwindow does not seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to adapt your code to work with a GUI. You can't introduce infinite loops in to tkinter GUI's without causing all sorts of problems.

Mainloop should only be called once.

I'd suggest that you move all of your scanning/saving operations in to a separate function which you schedule to occur periodically using the tkinter `after` method.

For example if you call your function `scan` you would schedule it to occur after 1 second using

```
root.after(1000, scan)
```

A more advanced method would be to have your scanning code running on a separate thread.

Also, you are currently trying to create the label each time you go round the while loop rather than just creating and packing them once and updating the text of the labels when you perform the "scanning". You can update the text of a label using the config method, for example

```
## Create a label
label1 = tk.Label(window,text = "PAKAVIMO OPERACIJA:")
##Pack the label
label1.pack()

## Update the text later
label1.config(text="New Text")
```

Here is an example of updating tkinter widgets periodically from a function.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def scanning():
    num = random.randint(0,100)
    entryTemperature.delete(0, tk.END) #Delete the current contents
    entryTemperature.insert(0, f"{num} K") #Add new text
    root.after(1000, scanning) #Schedule the function to run again in 1000ms (1 second)


root = tk.Tk()
entryTemperature = tk.Entry(root)
entryTemperature.grid(padx=50,pady=50)

root.after(1000, scanning)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for usefull tips. I will try to read and learn about tkinter after method. The most difficult part is to get the start of the program right. At the beggining of each operation user needs to scan a barcode , after that the GUI just need to update the text on the screen not much else. So if I can get the text updating to work that will be most of my GUI done. Also, does it matter where I call mainloop or that is not important as long as I call it atleast once

Comment: You should do all of your setup, create the GUI and then call mainloop. Once you call mainloop, no code beyond that line will be executed until the GUI is closed.

Comment: But how can I use my program then if no  code beyond mainloop will be executed? Because I need my program to run 24/7 so I cannot call mainloop?

Comment: @Lukas You schedule functions to be called with the `.after` method. The tkinter mainloop will execute these for you. Creating a GUI is a different method of programming where things happen on events like button presses or text being entered or in your case a function scheduled to execute periodically with `.after`

Comment: @Lukas I've added an example to my answer. Hopefully this answers your question and you might consider upvoting it or making it the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment again. Have you seen my previous answer that I have put an hour ago. I have managed to achieve sort of what I wanted without even using the event mainloop. Everything is running in my infinite loop and I just use window.update() to update text or whatever I need. What are the drawbacks of such GUI to the GUI that uses mainloop?. I dont really understand why calling mainloop is a necessary since I have achieved everything I needed without calling it

Comment: @Lukas, Disadvantage is that the GUI can't respond to button presses and other events. You might find that the window `hangs` if you try to use the close button too. You can get away without using mainloop, but it is far from recommended practice. This applies to other GUI frameworks too not just tkinter.

Comment: One more thing though. Are there any alternatives to using after() method since I do not think I can use that. I cannot know when an operato

Comment: @Lukas Looks like the last part of your comment is missing. Why don't you think after will work? If you read from the scanner every 1 second, you are unlikely to miss a person trying to scan something. You can always decrease the time. What does your scanning function currently do if there isn't anything to scan?

Comment: I mean once the item is scanned, the real "task" is then started. I do not want to scan anything untill the "task" is completed. Im not sure how after() works but I assumed it is going to keep calling the function every second or its going to call it 1 second after the previous one is completed? Also, could you have a look at my edited answer